# PostgreSQL: ERROR: syntax error at or near "-"

Tags: postgresql

Here I need to call a function with some parameters.

**Example**:

**Function**:

```
create or replace function testfunction(ids int,pcname varchar)
returns void as
$$
declare
       sql varchar;
       qu varchar := 'tabletemp_';
begin
       qu := qu ||ids ||'_'|| pcname;
       sql := 'Drop view if exists '||qu;

       raise info '%',sql;
       execute sql;
 end;
 $$
 language plpgsql;
```

**Calling Function**:

```
select testfunction(1,'abc-pc');
```

**Error**:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
Drop view if exists tabletemp_1_abc-pc
                                   ^
```

**Question**: How can I pass such parameter while calling function?

Comment: put the code for testfunction().

Comment: @Ilesh Patel, Please checkout the updated question. Thanks

Comment: @Meem do you think `select from testfunction(1,'abc-pc');`is  correct?  correct it

Comment: @dude, Yes! Done. That was the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `quote_ident`.

```
   sql := 'Drop view if exists '|| quote_ident(qu);
```

but you should preferably use `format`:

```
   sql := format('Drop view if exists %I', qu || ids ||'_'|| pcname);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
create or replace function testfunction(ids int,pcname varchar)
returns void as
$$
declare
       sql varchar;
       qu varchar := 'tabletemp_';
begin
       qu := qu ||ids ||'_'|| pcname;
       sql := 'Drop view if exists "'||qu||'"';

       raise info '%',sql;
       execute sql;
 end;
 $$
 language plpgsql;
```

Here I add double quote around table name.